# "Proprietary" HTML tags in HTML 4.01

Tags: javascript, html, dom

My last company, which used 4.01 DOCTYPE exclusively, decided to add some new functionality based on use of proprietary tags in the form of

```
<pp:foo attrOne="something" attrTwo="something else"/>
```

for certain purposes in their .aspx pages. In the beginning they broke a lot of Javascript until I sussed out that when these proprietary tags were self-closing, they caused (in some cases) the rest of the document to be interpreted as children of that element. (I should add that I didn't feel comfortable using proprietary tags in 4.01 in any case, but that decision was made above my pay grade.)

On the basis of my hunch, I suggested they change this to

```
<pp:foo attrOne="something" attrTwo="something else"></pp:foo>
```

and all the broken Javascript DOM manipulations came back right again. I couldn't find any reference to this kind of behavior anywhere, and fixing it was just a lucky guess on my part. My question is, does anyone know specifically why this should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You encountered this problem because [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/) does not support self-closing tags as in your first example.

Comment: Thanks all. In retrospect this seems obvious, but sometimes from the inside looking out we can't see the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 3):

The [W3C html validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) gives somewhat of an explanation:

> The sequence <FOO /> can be
>   interpreted in at least two different
>   ways, depending on the DOCTYPE of the
>   document.
>   For HTML 4.01 Strict, the
>   '/' terminates the tag <FOO (with an
>   implied '>').
>   However, since many
>   browsers don't interpret it this way,
>   even in the presence of an HTML 4.01
>   Strict DOCTYPE, it is best to avoid it
>   completely in pure HTML documents and
>   reserve its use solely for those
>   written in XHTML.